# Sort Array by key value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this Array:

```
Array
(
    [Alben] => Array
        (
            [Sgt._Pepper’s_Lonely_Hearts_Club_Band] => 
            [Rubber_Soul] => 
            [Please_Please_Me] => 
            [Let_It_Be_(Album)] => 
            [With_the_Beatles] => 
            [Let_It_Be…_Naked] => 
            [A_Hard_Day’s_Night_(Album)] => Rickenbacker_360-12WB_12_String.jpg
            [Beatles_for_Sale] => 
            [Help!_(Album)] => Semaphore_Victor.svg
            [Magical_Mystery_Tour_(Album)] => 
            [The_Beatles_(Album)] => 
            [Yellow_Submarine] => 
            [Abbey_Road] => The_End.jpg
            [Revolver_(Album)] => 
            [Anthology_(The_Beatles)] => 
            [A_Collection_of_Oldies_…_but_Goldies] => 
            [1_(Album)] => 
        )

)
```

Now I want to sort it by the value. 
So, that the keys are first which have an img in the value. And the entries without among them. I tried `array_values` but it returns the same Array. Maybe cause the key '`Alben`'?

I tried:

`$returnArray = array_values($returnArray);`

Comment: You don't want to use `array_values()` here. You'll lose your indexes.

Comment: You could simply do something like: `array_flip($array); ksort($array); array_flip($array);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_values` will return you an array with just values and break your association. You may need to use the [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function to do this, where you can provide a custom sorting logic to your values and maintain index association. **From PHP Docs:**

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements they are associated with, using a
>   user-defined comparison function.
>
> This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual
>   element order is significant.

(from it's derivation `usort` comes:)

> **`value_compare_func`**
>
> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Here's an example upon the code you provided:

```
<?php
// array reproducing
$collection = array(
        "Alben" => array (
                "Sgt._Pepper’s_Lonely_Hearts_Club_Band" => "",
                "Rubber_Soul" => "",
                "Please_Please_Me" => "",
                "Let_It_Be_(Album)" => "",
                "With_the_Beatles" => "",
                "Let_It_Be…_Naked" => "",
                "A_Hard_Day’s_Night_(Album)" => "Rickenbacker_360-12WB_12_String.jpg",
                "Beatles_for_Sale" => "",
                "Help!_(Album)" => "Semaphore_Victor.svg",
                "Magical_Mystery_Tour_(Album)" => "",
                "The_Beatles_(Album)" => "ble_test",
                "Yellow_Submarine" => "",
                "Abbey_Road" => "The_End.jpg",
                "Revolver_(Album)" => "",
                "Anthology_(The_Beatles)" => "",
                "A_Collection_of_Oldies_…_but_Goldies" => "",
                "1_(Album)" => "",
        ));

// callback of sorting, checks if the compared value is not empty then pushes it ahead.
// If not, pull it backwards.
$sortIfFilled = function ($a, $b) {
    return (!$a) ? 1 : -1;
};

// Executing it...
uasort($collection['Alben'], $sortIfFilled);

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($collection);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [Alben] => Array
        (
            [The_Beatles_(Album)] => ble_test
            [Abbey_Road] => The_End.jpg
            [A_Hard_Day’s_Night_(Album)] => Rickenbacker_360-12WB_12_String.jpg
            [Help!_(Album)] => Semaphore_Victor.svg
            [Yellow_Submarine] => 
            [Let_It_Be…_Naked] => 
            [A_Collection_of_Oldies_…_but_Goldies] => 
            [Let_It_Be_(Album)] => 
            [Revolver_(Album)] => 
            [Beatles_for_Sale] => 
            [With_the_Beatles] => 
            [Sgt._Pepper’s_Lonely_Hearts_Club_Band] => 
            [Rubber_Soul] => 
            [Magical_Mystery_Tour_(Album)] => 
            [Anthology_(The_Beatles)] => 
            [Please_Please_Me] => 
            [1_(Album)] => 
        )

)
```

Consider a careful reading of callback functions on PHP Docs, they might help you with similar issues along your projects.